# Arduino Error (C++) : invalid use of non-static data member

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, arduino

I am making a scalable Arduino library but I receive the compiler-error: `invalid use of non-static data member`.

My Code:
LedCube.h:

```
#ifndef LedCube_h
#define LedCube_h
#include "Arduino.h"
class LedCube {
  private:
  int _x, _y, _z;
  byte _lPins[_y];
  byte _cPins[_z][_x];
  public:
  LedCube(int x, int y, int z, byte *lPins, byte (*cPins)[_x]);
  void displayFrame(bool frame[][_x][_z]);
  void displayLayer(int i, bool frame[][_x][_z]);
};
#endif
```

Ledcube.ino(cpp):

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "LedCube.h"

int _x, _y, _z;
//bool frame[y][z][x] = {0};
byte _lPins[_y];
byte _cPins[_z][_x];

LedCube::LedCube(int x, int y, int z, byte lPins[], byte cPins[][_x]) {
  _x = x;
  _y = y;
  _z = z;
  _lPins = lPins;
  _cPins = cPins;
}

void LedCube::displayFrame(bool frame[_y][_x][_z]) {
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<_y;i++) {
    displayLayer(i, frame);
    pinMode(_lPins[i], OUTPUT);
    delay(1);
    pinMode(_lPins[i], INPUT);
  }
}

void LedCube::displayLayer(int i, bool frame[_y][_x][_z]) {
  int j,k;
  for(j=0;j<_z;j++) {
    for(k=0;k<_x;k++) {
      if(frame[i][j][k]) {
        digitalWrite(_cPins[j][k], HIGH);
      }
      else {
        digitalWrite(_cPins[j][k], LOW);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to accept the variables `x`, `y` and `z` and set these to `_x`, `_y` and `_z` in the constructor, and hence do not want to set the variables `static`.
I am using these variables to declare a loop.

The error I get is:

```
Arduino: 1.6.5 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"

In file included from LedCube.ino:2:0:
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_y'
   int _x, _y, _z;
           ^
LedCube.h:13: error: from this location
   byte _lPins[_y];
               ^
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_z'
   int _x, _y, _z;
               ^
LedCube.h:14: error: from this location
   byte _cPins[_z][_x];
               ^
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_x'
   int _x, _y, _z;
       ^
LedCube.h:14: error: from this location
   byte _cPins[_z][_x];
                   ^
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_x'
   int _x, _y, _z;
       ^
LedCube.h:16: error: from this location
   LedCube(int x, int y, int z, byte *lPins, byte (*cPins)[_x]);
                                                           ^
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_x'
   int _x, _y, _z;
       ^
LedCube.h:17: error: from this location
   void displayFrame(bool frame[][_x][_z]);
                                  ^
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_z'
   int _x, _y, _z;
               ^
LedCube.h:17: error: from this location
   void displayFrame(bool frame[][_x][_z]);
                                      ^
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_x'
   int _x, _y, _z;
       ^
LedCube.h:18: error: from this location
   void displayLayer(int i, bool frame[][_x][_z]);
                                         ^
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_z'
   int _x, _y, _z;
               ^
LedCube.h:18: error: from this location
   void displayLayer(int i, bool frame[][_x][_z]);
                                             ^
LedCube:6: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
LedCube:7: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
LedCube:7: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
In file included from LedCube.ino:2:0:
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_x'
   int _x, _y, _z;
       ^
LedCube:9: error: from this location
LedCube.ino: In constructor 'LedCube::LedCube(...)':
LedCube:10: error: 'x' was not declared in this scope
LedCube:11: error: 'y' was not declared in this scope
LedCube:12: error: 'z' was not declared in this scope
LedCube:13: error: '_lPins' was not declared in this scope
LedCube:13: error: 'lPins' was not declared in this scope
LedCube:14: error: '_cPins' was not declared in this scope
LedCube:14: error: 'cPins' was not declared in this scope
In file included from LedCube.ino:2:0:
LedCube.h: At global scope:
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_y'
   int _x, _y, _z;
           ^
LedCube:17: error: from this location
In file included from LedCube.ino:2:0:
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_x'
   int _x, _y, _z;
       ^
LedCube:17: error: from this location
In file included from LedCube.ino:2:0:
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_z'
   int _x, _y, _z;
               ^
LedCube:17: error: from this location
LedCube.ino: In member function 'void LedCube::displayFrame(...)':
LedCube:20: error: 'frame' was not declared in this scope
LedCube:21: error: '_lPins' was not declared in this scope
In file included from LedCube.ino:2:0:
LedCube.h: At global scope:
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_y'
   int _x, _y, _z;
           ^
LedCube:27: error: from this location
In file included from LedCube.ino:2:0:
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_x'
   int _x, _y, _z;
       ^
LedCube:27: error: from this location
In file included from LedCube.ino:2:0:
LedCube.h:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_z'
   int _x, _y, _z;
               ^
LedCube:27: error: from this location
LedCube.ino: In member function 'void LedCube::displayLayer(...)':
LedCube:31: error: 'frame' was not declared in this scope
LedCube:31: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
LedCube:32: error: '_cPins' was not declared in this scope
LedCube:35: error: '_cPins' was not declared in this scope
invalid use of non-static data member 'LedCube::_y'

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

I just want to target this error and not the others in the output.

Comment: You can't do `byte _lPins[_y];`. But you can use a `std::vector<byte>` and set its length in a constructor initializer list. Problem: an Arduino compiler may not necessarily support the C++ standard library, like `std::vector`. Solution: find such implementation on the net.

Comment: Why do you have a class member `_lPins` and also a global variable `_lPins` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class LedCube {
  private:
  int _x, _y, _z;
  byte _lPins[_y];
  byte _cPins[_z][_x];
```

The above code doesn't make any sense, Arduino or not. (Bear in mind Arduino uses C++).

You are trying to define arrays `_lPins` and `_cPins` which have lengths `_x, _y, _z` which are uninitialized. A class has to have a fixed size, so that when you instantiate it, the compiler knows how much memory to allocate it (before calling the constructor). How can it allocate memory for unknown sized arrays?

---

*(Edited to add)*

> I think StackOverflow has a constructive answers policy. Please do give a solution if you think I did something wrong (which is why I am here).

I'm interested to know why you accept an answer which says "Your code: ... is wrong." but take offence at mine. The accepted answer posts no solution code, just some guidelines.

This code of yours, not in the class definition, also makes the same mistake:

```
int _x, _y, _z;
//bool frame[y][z][x] = {0};
byte _lPins[_y];
byte _cPins[_z][_x];
```

That also generates an error. You can't declare a static array like that, with bounds of `x, _y, _z` where `x, _y, _z` are not constants. The array won't redefine its length in the future when you change `x, _y, _z`.

---

In your constructor you are passing as an argument, a name _x which is also a class variable.

```
LedCube::LedCube(int x, int y, int z, byte lPins[], byte cPins[][_x]) {
```

---

C++ doesn't let you assign arrays like this:

```
 _lPins = lPins;
 _cPins = cPins;
```

---

You have a lot of errors, not just one, eg.

```
LedCube:20: error: 'frame' was not declared in this scope
LedCube:21: error: '_lPins' was not declared in this scope
```

You really should go through and clean them all up.

---

> Likewise, IIRC, new and delete are also not provided on your platform

Actually the Arduino provides `new` and `delete`, as well as `malloc` and `free`.

---

I'm trying to be constructive, but there is no one-line fix. A rework is needed, sorry to tell you. And you might want to do some C++ tutorials. The code you are writing (although I can see what you are trying to do) is you *hoping* that the language works in a certain way, when it just doesn't.

---

#### Possible implementation

Below is a possible way of allocating the pin structures in the constructor, based on supplied array sizes. I don't think this is a great implementation, but at least it works. The `showPins` function shows that the data has been correctly retained.

```
class LedCube {
  private:
    const int x_, y_, z_;
    byte * lPins_;
    byte * cPins_;
  public:
    LedCube(const int x, const int y, const int z, byte *lPins, byte *cPins);  // constructor

    void showPins () const;
};

byte lPins [3] = { 5, 6, 7 };
byte cPins [2] [4] = {
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },    // 0
    { 8, 9, 10, 11 },  // 1
};

LedCube::LedCube (const int x, const int y, const int z, byte *lPins, byte *cPins)
    : x_ (x), y_ (y), z_ (z)
  {
  lPins_ = new byte [y];
  cPins_ = new byte [x * z];
  if (lPins_ == NULL || cPins_ == NULL)
    exit (1);
  memcpy (lPins_, lPins, sizeof (byte) * y);
  memcpy (cPins_, cPins, sizeof (byte) * x * z);
  }

void LedCube::showPins () const
  {
  Serial.println (F("lPins:"));
  for (int i = 0; i < y_; i++)
    Serial.println (lPins_ [i]);
  Serial.println (F("cPins:"));
  for (int j = 0; j < x_; j++)
    {
    Serial.print (F("z = "));
    Serial.println (j);
    for (int k = 0; k < z_; k++)
      Serial.println (cPins_ [j * z_ + k]);
    } 
  }

LedCube foo (2, 3, 4, (byte *) lPins, (byte *) cPins);

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();
  foo.showPins ();
}

void loop() 
{

}
```

Output:

```
lPins:
5
6
7
cPins:
z = 0
1
2
3
4
z = 1
8
9
10
11
```

Comment: I am writing a library and the quoted code is from the header file which contains just the declarations.
The variables are being initialized in the .ino file by the constructor.

Comment: I think StackOverflow has a constructive answers policy. Please do give a solution if you think I did something wrong (which is why I am here).

Comment: "Giving a solution" is more than correcting a line of code in this particular case. It is basically a rewrite. See my amended answer.

Comment: @Nick_Gammon Sorry for the misunderstanding. Actually this is my first attempt at writing complex C++ code after 2012, and that too on a new platform. And by "giving a solution" I meant anything like reading material or guidlines to point me in the correct direction. I accepted the other person's answer becase his/hers answer was the only available one at that moment (Other Person: Please don't mind). Also I just want different but constant length arrays in different objects. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: @sbrm1 First, I don't mind!  But also, you may consider making the array size a non-type template parameter.  It's worth noting, though, that if you will need a large number of differently-sized cubes, it's possible that you might encounter code-size issues, depending on the number of template instantiations present and the cleverness of your compiler's optimizer.  This is worth considering, I think, because the resulting code will be simpler --- dynamic allocation should be avoided if possible.

Comment: `I don't want VLAs, just different sized arrays in different objects of the class, which would be constant in their respective instances.` - see amended answer.

Comment: BTW - I've renamed your variables. The C++ standard reserves variable names starting with an underscore in the global namespace.

Comment: @Nick_Gammon Wish I could upvote thrice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:  `byte _lPins[_y];  byte _cPins[_z][_x];` is wrong.  C++ does not support variable-length arrays, meaning that `_y`, `_x`, `_z` must be constant expressions.

Remember that the size of an object must be constant at compile time, and you won't make that error again.

The "correct" way to approach this problem is to use a `std::vector`, but I believe that it does not exist on your platform, though you should check.  IIRC, the only library available is a subset of standard C that comes from avr-libc.

You will have to dynamically-allocate the memory as you need it yourself.  Likewise, IIRC, `new` and `delete` are also not provided on your platform (but again, you'll have to check me on that), so you'll have to use `malloc` and `free` and do things the old C way.   There's plenty of resources available on how to do that online.

Comment: Just to note, I am using the Arduino IDE which basically implements the Wiring language specification.

Comment: avr-gcc and avr-libc are not used, and the specification may be different.

Comment: Even if C++ did support VLAs, you still couldn't use them in a struct. Size of struct must be known at compile-time for obvious reasons.

Comment: @sbrm1 According to [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess), avr-gcc is used in the back-end.

Comment: @Max_Bozzi Okay, but it is a different specification than what is used in AVR Studio, which, I assume, you were talking about. Arduino supports `new` and `delete`. @M.M I don't want VLAs, just different sized arrays in different objects of the class, which would be constant in their respective instances.